# FatalErrorException in Manager.php line 139 on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, upgrade, laravel-5.4, laravel-upgrade

After upgrade Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4
Show me this error

> FatalErrorException in Manager.php line 138:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calls to the ->set() method should be changed to ->put(). Typically, Laravel applications would never call the set method since it has never been documented within the Laravel documentation. However, it is included here out of caution.

**Topic in documentation**

Sessions

Symfony Compatibility

for more information to read laravel 5.4 documentation [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade)